# Additional images not showing in product details page- magento 2

Tags: product-images, product-view, magento-2.1.1

Facing problem while displaying additional images in magento 2 product details page, only showing base images but in backend images are there, do I need to write any separate api for showing additional images in pdp page

Comment: product additional images showing by default. have modify code related to images ?

Comment: will it depends on image dimension

Comment: you can look this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/product-image-not-showing-in-detail-page/147429#147429. It may help you.