# Product Image Not Showing in detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I used Ubertheme migration tool to migration of data from Magento 1 to magento2. 
Migration is done successfully, but after that, I face one issue.

Product Image shows in category list page on frontside and product grid in admin side.
When I open product detail page in front and admin side, I am not able to see product image.

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: Try to inspect element using fiebug & check for image URL & try to open

Comment: @AnkitShah it show default placehoder url in both places.

Comment: R u able to open image? Image path is correct?

Comment: @AnkitShah Image is properly display in category page and admin grid, if i copy that url then it also open in browser as well.

Comment: Try to add new simple product from admin & check on frontend for detail page. Check `.htaccess` as well

Comment: If I upload new image then it will show fine every where, But my problem with already existing image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47151/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-dhiren-vasoya).

Comment: `var\view_preprocessed\source` remove `frontend`Delete that folder
Run
Below commands in order
`rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/*` `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` 
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 2):

I found solution using this script,

In above condition, product image are already assign in database but not show in frontend, you can do this using this script.

You need to do following things,

1. Create one file in magento root directories, let say file name is **"Productimage.php"**
2. Put the following code into that file,

   ```
   <?php 
   use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
   require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

   $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

   $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

   $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
   $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

   try
   {
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $importDir = __DIR__ . '/pub/media/catalog/product';
       $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(YOURPRODUCTID);

           if($product->getImage() != '')
           {
               $id = $product->getId();
               $url = $importDir . $product->getImage();
               $product->addImageToMediaGallery($url, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
               $product->save();
               echo "<br /><br /> $id Product Save Succefully";
           }

   }
   catch(\Exception $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       exit;
   }
   ```

NOTE: replace YOURPRODUCTID with your real Id.

Answer (score 1):

We wonder which migration tool you referred to. We have old script on Github which is no longer maintained and replaced with a newer version UB Data Migration.

The issue you mentioned might occur with the old script, but not [our latest migration tool V3](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found solution and I already posted answer above.

Comment: Our old script on Github was developed long ago, since the initial release of Magento 2 which might come with unexpected issue.

Comment: That's why we refer to our newer version. Anyway, glad that you figured it out at your end.

Answer (score 0):

```
-> Give permissions to pub/media folder chmod 777 -R pub/media/
-> bin/magento c:c
-> bin/magento c:f
```